# Logging Rust programs

Tags: logging, rust

If we have following code

```
fn main() {
    error!("This is an error log")
    warn!("This is a warn log")
    info!("this is an info log")
    debug!("This is a debug log")
}
```

How do we enable the debug level output on Windows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When executing your program, you need to set the `RUST_LOG` environment variable appropriately; it is (as far as this is concerned) a comma-separated key=value list; the keys are crate or module names, e.g. `extra` or `std::option`; the values are numbers, mapped to log levels:

- 1: error
- 2: warn
- 3: info
- 4: debug

(Each level includes the more significant levels.)

In Command Prompt, compiling and running `myprog` with showing warnings and errors would be something like:

```
rustc myprog.rs
set RUST_LOG=myprog=4
myprog.exe
```

Comment: `debug` requires compiling the program with `--cfg debug` too: they get entirely removed without it.

Comment: I tried to edit your question dbaupps suggestion, but it seems to have been rejected. could you change that snippet above to set `RUST_LOG=myprog=4\n  rustc myprog.rs --cfg debug\n myprog.exe`?

Comment: Recently, `--cfg=debug` isn't needed, this is on by default, and if you odn't want it, you need `--cfg=nodebug`

Comment: @SteveKlabnik Actually, it's `--cfg ndebug`

Answer (score 7):

If you look at [env_logger documentation](https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.9.0/env_logger/index.html) it says:

> "by default all logging is disabled except for the error level."

You set an ENVIRONMENT variable.  In your case: `RUST_LOG=debug`.

```
extern crate env_logger;
extern crate log;
use log::{debug, error, info, warn};


fn main() {
    env_logger::init();

    error!("[!]  error");
    warn!("[!]   warn");
    info!("[!]   info");
    debug!("[!]  debug");
}

/*
[2021-08-19T13:14:15Z ERROR cliapp] [!]  error
[2021-08-19T13:14:15Z WARN  cliapp] [!]   warn
[2021-08-19T13:14:15Z INFO  cliapp] [!]   info
[2021-08-19T13:14:15Z DEBUG cliapp] [!]  debug
*/
```

**CLion** tip ->

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can set the logging level in the program by setting them to your environment as well. The statement you have to write is:

```
RUST_LOG=YOUR-PROJECT-NAME=log_level
```

eg:
`RUST_LOG=Hello-World=info` or `RUST_LOG=Hello-World=3`

After setting your log level the next step is to initialize them by using **env_logger::init()**.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is helpful for people. Below is my solution for using log. I wanted to turn on by default, instead of controlling log via environment variables.

Add this code before you issue log statements.

```
// enable logging, since log defaults to silent
std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "info");
env_logger::init();
```

...

```
debug!("LOGGING **************************");
info!("LOGGING **************************");
error!("LOGGING **************************");
```

Then, all of these will output to stdout.

[Here are the log docs](https://docs.rs/log/latest/log/).